# Mocking or testing an interface in Junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, mockito, junit5

I have a CMS (Content management System) to store property key values.

```
public interface CMSConfig {
  @Property(propertyName = "someConfig")
  String getSomeConfig();
}
```

And the Configuration annotation code is

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Configuration {
    String configName() default "";
}
```

And the way to call this CMS is

```
@Service
public class MockitoService {

  @ManagedConfiguration
  private CMSConfig cmsConfig;

  public String method() {
    return "Hello!" + cmsConfig.getSomeConfig();
  }
}
```

ManagedConfiguration.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ManagedConfiguration {
}
```

I am looking to do the UnitTest for CMSConfig

I am not able to Mock or create the bean of CMSConfig as it's an interface. I have tried multiple approaches.

My UnitTest case file is

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockitoServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  MockitoService mockitoService;

  @ManagedConfiguration
  private CMSConfig cmsConfig;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void before() {
    System.setProperty("cms.configs.dir", Paths.get("src", "main", "resources").toFile().getAbsolutePath());
  }

  @Test
  public void testCMS(){
    assertEquals(cmsConfig.getDummy(),"dummyvalueUatRes");
  }
}
```

Please help if there's any way to do this.
My mockitoService and cmsConfig are null while running the test case.

Comment: May I ask why you arent using @Configuration for your config class but choose to use an interface

Comment: Testing an interface without any implementation for it is basically impossible. What do you think you are testing in this case? Additionally, why would `CMSConfig` be an interface and not a regular class?